# Facebook application Django server connection

Tags: python, django, facebook, networking

I am creating a Facebook application in Python and Django. I followed all the instructions mentioned on this page: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:PyFacebook_Tutorial. But it ended up giving me this error:

> The URL http://amitverma.dyndns.org/fbsample/?auth_token=0e80c8dbba442763d2c539d6e64e992a is not valid.
>   Please try again later. We appreciate your patience as the developers of roadies and Facebook resolve this issue. Thanks!

Now here is the lowdown:

I am on a [ADSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_Digital_Subscriber_Line) modem/routed network with dynamic addressing. I tried to forward my port, 80 and 8080 on 192.168.2.2. That's my static IP address. I guess this is not visible from the Internet. Then I created a dynamic DNS through [DynDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS), : amitverma.dyndns.org, but still no go.

I have to run a simple server of sorts to make Django run. I make the server run like this: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`. The `0.0.0.0` is the IP address and 80 is the port number. What should I enter in the Facebook application edit settings page in the field that says *Canvas page URL*?

My Facebook application canvas URL is: amitverma.dyndns.org/fbsample/. When I access it, it gives me the above error.

I have spent the last 10 hours fiddling with this and still can't seem to make it run.

PS: Please don't say it's not a programming question. I think more than networking, it's something else I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You need to troubleshoot from somewhere outside your development box and local network. You need to figure out if this is a DNS issue, a port forwarding issue, or perhaps an issue on your dev. box (is a local firewall blocking the requests?).

From a network location outside your home network, connect using the router's public IP address to see if the port forwarding works. try to ping the dns address, check that it resolves correctly etc.

You could create a Amazon EC2 virtual machine and do the troubleshooting from there (that will be your 'outside' network location).

**EDIT:**

You have dyndns set up wrong.

```
$ nslookup amitverma.dyndns.org
Server:         10.0.0.1
Address:        10.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   amitverma.dyndns.org
Address: 192.168.1.5
```

192.168.* is your internal IP address (it is in the [reserved private IPv4 address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)). DNS should point to your router's public IP address. http://whatismyipaddress.com/ will tell you what your router's public IP address is at the moment.